# Simple news from activate the user after email confirmation click in email

Tags: 7, emails

I'm using the [Simplenews](https://www.drupal.org/project/simplenews) module after user received the subscription link through email,when click on the link user automatically subscription the news letter.

I don't know how to do this. I checked the setting there is no default activation option.

Comment: you just need to go thorough how to use and setup, below are some links for tutorial. I am using this module and is working great:

https://modulesunraveled.com/simplenews


http://getlevelten.com/blog/colin/creating-e-mail-newsletter-simplenews